# outlook options trust center setting automation using powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365

[image: Registry for Mail options Image]

I am planning to automate the outlook settings using powershell.

Objective is to enable "Read as Plain Text" under outlook File>Options>Trust Center>Trust Center Settings>Email Security>Read all standard mail in plain text(enable).

Instead of navigating manually, am planning to update the registry entry for "Read as Plain Text" using powershell but there is no such registry entry.

Hence created in registry Mail key and readasplain REG_DWORD.

**But the issue is any changes in outlook reflecting in registry but changes in registry not reflecting in outlook application. During testing rebooted system as well.**

Kindly could advise how to automate this setting using powershell.

Answer (score 0):

The value is stored in the registry at

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
```

Value Name - readasplain
Value Type - REG_DWORD
Enabled Value - 1
Disabled Value - 0

Note, if a group policy is set, its key is at

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
```

Outlook should be restarted to apply such changes.

Comment: Hi Eugene, I did tried updated the registry setting and rebooted system, but not reflecting changes in outlook. However any changes in outlook application reflecting in the registry.

Comment: Does your Outlook version correspond to the path numbers?

Comment: Hi Eugene, the outlook version is 2016 and created the registry entry in the appropriate path. Attached the image in the modified comment.

The issue is if by enabling the **Read all standard mail in plain text** in the outlook application, it automatically updates in the registry.

But If i enable **readasplain** in registry as shown in the image, the changes not reflecting in outlook application. kindly advise.

Comment: Did you try to set the setting and then check out the windows registry keys after closing Outlook?

Comment: yes Eugene. I did closed the outlook, rebooted the system but any changes in registry not reflecting in outlook.